# If else java set sql column value

Tags: java, sql, if-statement

I hope someone can help me, I am a novice at Java and I need to understand how I can populate a SQL returned column with the result from the if statement below.

If the result is true I need the EUR to display the value from the CN* else just return the amount field.

```
   if(returnt.getString("ins_type",i).contains("A DRAWDOWN")
        || returnt.getString("ins_type",i).contains("B DRAWDOWN"))
       returnt.setDouble("eur", i, -1 * Str.strToDouble(returnt.getString("CN*", i)));
    else
       returnt.setDouble("eur", i, returnt.getDouble("amount", i));
```

Thanks,
RM

Comment: insufficient information. What is your expectation and what is the current behavior? Also the code doesn't seem enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to write the column `eur`. Then you need an SQL UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET eur = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
WHERE ...
```

Instead of executeQuery, executeUpdate.

BTW better use BigDecimal instead of double in java, and in SQL DECIMAL is a safe bet to have a correct precision.

---

***Example of dumping a query:***

```
String sql = "SELECT ins_type, amount, cn_amount, cn_quantity"
    + " FROM tbl"
    + " WHERE priority > ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInteger(1, priority);
    try (ResultSet returnt = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        String insType = returnt.getString("ins_type");
        double amount = returnt.getDouble("amount");
        double cnAmout = returnt.getDouble("cn_amount");
        double eur = insType.contains("A DRAWDOWN")
                || insType.contains("B DRAWDOWN")
            ? -1 * cnAmount
            : amount;
        // or-operator: || ; if-then-else expression: cond ? a : b

        System.out.println("| " + insType + " | " + eur + " |");
    } // Ensures returnt.closed() is called for you.
} // Ensures stmt.closed() is called for you.
```

Comment: I am a novice, I am not sure where I would put the update command.  Can I not use and if else to set the EUR value?

Comment: This answer assumes you want to write the `eur` field back to the database. (Otherwise you could just store the result in a local double var. Then you do not need to perform an SQL SELECT for that purpose, but can use an SQL UPDATE. And in SQL the most standard if-then-else expression/function is `CASE WHEN condition THEN truth ELSE alternative END`

Comment: I don't want to write the value back to the datatbase I just want to populate a value in the EUR column. Everything I have tried so far ends up with EUR returning nothing.

Comment: A ResultSet is intended as read-only data, place the fields in proper java vars. Sorry that I misunderstood.

Comment: Hi, sorry I really am a novice, would you be able to provide an example?